# dnsdisplay returns name does not exists

Tags: networking

I execute the command `ipconfig /displaydns` on win10 . But it returns

```
teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com  
-------------------------
name does not exists
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Works fine here - two machines 1 Windows 10 1 Windows 11.  Run DISM and SFC.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: You might also run TCP/IP Reset.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer